# WebBrowser InvokeScript()

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I need to execute an JavaScript function from my Visual C++ Code with the return value of the JavaScript function. In my Windows Visual C++ CLR project I have an Windows Form with an WebBrowser in it.

I tried:

```
Object^ result = webBrowser1->Document->InvokeScript("document.getElementById('communication').innerHTML;");
String^ resutlString = result->ToString();
```

Using this i get the Error `'System.NullReferenceException` As far as I know this means smth like `result` equals null.

Actually not even this

```
webBrowser1->Document->InvokeScript("document.getElementById('communication').innerHTML = 'test';")
```

is doing anything.

**Edit:**

It seems I did't understand the method `InvokeScript` right you have to pass a JavaScript function name not just any JavaScript Code `webBrowser1->Document->InvokeScript("jsFunction")` is working but I'm still getting `'System.NullReferenceException` when trying to Convert result to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok everything seems to work I had a typo in my JavaScript so the function never returned anything